# Tensorflow: reduce_mean of subtensors and concatenating the results

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I have a 3D tensor with shape `(X,Y,Z)`. Only Z is known in advance, everything else is determined at running time. I have an integer `N` s.t N divides X. I would like to do an operation similar to `tf.reduce_mean` on one axis without completely getting rid of the axis I'm taking the mean along. Another way of seeing this is as a `tf.reduce_mean` operation on subtensors of dimension `(X/N, Y, Z)` and concatenating the results back. So the final shape of my 3D tensor would be `(N,Y,Z)`

So given N=2 and the following 3D tensor

```
          [[[1., 2.],
            [3., 4.],
            [5., 6.]],

           [[7., 8.],
            [9., 0.],
            [1., 2.]],

           [[3., 4.],
            [5., 6.],
            [7., 8.]],

           [[9., 0.],
            [1., 2.],
            [3., 4.]]

           [[5., 6.],
            [7., 8.],
            [9., 0.]]

           [[1., 2.],
            [3., 4.],
            [5., 6.]]]
```

the new 3D tensor should be

```
          [[[3.66, 4.66],
            [5.66, 2.66],
            [4.33, 5.33]],

           [[5 , 2.66],
            [3.66 , 4.66],
            [5.66 , 3.33]]]
```

I've looked around for a bit in both the tensorflow documentation and on this website, but couldn't find anything. Any insights on what the simplest/most efficient way of doing this is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following process accomplishes what you want.  The idea is to split the input tensor, compute the mean on the individual tensors, and then stack the result.  It is not the most efficient possible thing, since there will be memory allotted for the reduced means, and then separate memory allotted for the stacked result.  However, I am unaware of a way to do this better without writing custom under-the-covers code.

```
>>> in_tensor = tf.constant([[[1, 2],
...             [3, 4],
...             [5, 6]],
... 
...            [[7, 8],
...             [9, 0],
...             [1, 2]],
... 
...            [[3 , 4],
...             [5 , 6],
...             [7 , 8]],
... 
...            [[9 , 0],
...             [1 , 2],
...             [3 , 4]]] )
>>> slice1 = in_tensor[0:2,:,:]
>>> slice2 = in_tensor[2:,...]
>>> mean1 = tf.reduce_mean(slice1, axis=0)
>>> mean2 = tf.reduce_mean(slice2, axis=0)
>>> stacked = tf.stack([mean1,mean2],axis=0)
>>> with tf.Session() as sess:
...   sess.run(stacked)

array([[[4, 5],
        [6, 2],
        [3, 4]],

       [[6, 2],
        [3, 4],
        [5, 6]]], dtype=int32)
```

Comment: yes, but that still "collapses" all rows along that dimension instead of keeping N of them

Comment: So, looking at your example, you want to perform `reduce_mean` on a sub-tensor of the original tensor, and then concatenate the results (or something functionally equivalent to that)?

Comment: yes, I would like to know what the best way of doing so is

Comment: Please clarify your question to reflect this, and I will answer it.

Comment: I edited the title, added some extra text and improved the example